# What is the returned hostname when client is localhost?

Tags: java, networking, localhost, client-server, hostname

I am applying a simple client server tutorial in Java as follows:

```
public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
        s.close();
    }
}
public class Server{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        InetAddress inetAddress = s.getInetAddress();
        System.out.println("Client's host name is " + inetAddress.getHostName());
        System.out.println("Client's IP Address is " + inetAddress.getHostAddress());
        ss.close();     s.close();
    }
}
```

As shown, there is a couple of lines to get the hostname and address of connected client in the server code.
When running on my computer (localhost) the IP is correct as 127.0.0.1 but the hostname is confusing for me:

```
Client's host name is lm.licenses.adobe.com
Client's IP Address is 127.0.0.1
```

Why the hostname of my computer (localhost) is read as Adobe?

Comment: Which os do you use? Any entries in the hosts file?

Comment: Windows 11. Do not know about the hosts file. Any details?

Comment: https://beebom.com/how-find-edit-hosts-file-windows-11/

Comment: Yes, I found lm.licenses.adobe.com there. I think it is related to a crack or something. I think I understood somehow. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your computer's hosts file to see if there is an entry associating the IP address **127.0.0.1** with the hostname **"lm.licenses.adobe.com"**. The hosts file is typically located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on **Windows** or `/etc/hosts` on **Unix-based systems**.

Open the hosts file and ensure that there are no unexpected entries associating **127.0.0.1** with **"lm.licenses.adobe.com"**.